# Cannot run a simple application in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I wrote a simple application in Erlang, but it refuses to work with the following error:

```
   =SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 18-Jan-2012::15:03:27 ===
 Supervisor: {<0.60.0>,my_sup}
 Context:    start_error
 Reason:     {'EXIT',{undef,[{my,start,[{8077,none}]},
                             {supervisor,do_start_child,2},
                             {supervisor,start_children,3},
                             {supervisor,init_children,2},
                             {gen_server,init_it,6},
                             {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}}
 Offender:   [{pid,undefined},
              {name,my},
              {mfa,{my,start,[{8077,none}]}},
              {restart_type,permanent},
              {shutdown,brutal_kill},
              {child_type,worker}]

=INFO REPORT==== 18-Jan-2012::15:03:27 ===
application: my
exited: {shutdown,{my_app,start,[normal,[noarg]]}}
type: temporary {error,{shutdown,{my_app,start,[normal,[noarg]]}}}
```

And the modules:

my.erl

```
-module(my).
-export([start/2, stop/0]).

start(Port,_arg) ->
 io:format("starting my").

stop() ->
  ok.
```

my_app.erl Application module, perform  `application` behavior.

```
 -module(my_app).
 -behaviour(application).
 -export([start/2, stop/1]).

  start(_Type, _Args) ->
   io:format("my server starting~n"),
   my_sup:start_link().

  stop(_State) ->
   io:format("my server terminating~n"),
   ok.
```

my_sup.erl Supervisor logic

```
-module(my_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1]).

start_link() ->
  supervisor:start_link(my_sup, []).

init(_Args) ->
 {ok, {
       {one_for_one, 10, 60},
          [{my, {my, start, [{8077,none}]
       },
        permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [my]}]}}.
```

Config file (my.app):

```
 {application, my,
 [
  {description, "Demo"},
  {vsn, "1.0"},
  {id, "hello"},
  {modules,      [my,my_sup]},
  {registered,   [my,my_sup]},
  {applications, [kernel, stdlib]},
  %%
  %% mod: Specify the module name to start the application, plus args
  %%
  {mod, {my_app, [noarg]}},
  {env, []}
  ]
 }.
```

I changed child spec like you recommend, but the problem still remains.

```
 =SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 19-Jan-2012::00:34:21 ===
 Supervisor: {<0.96.0>,my_sup}
 Context:    start_error
 Reason:     <0.97.0>
 Offender:   [{pid,undefined},
          {name,my},
          {mfa,{my,start,[8077,none]}},
          {restart_type,permanent},
          {shutdown,brutal_kill},
          {child_type,worker}]


=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Jan-2012::00:34:21 ===
Error in process <0.97.0> with exit value: 
{{badmatch,{error,eaddrinuse}},[{my,'-       start/2-fun-0-',1}]}


=INFO REPORT==== 19-Jan-2012::00:34:21 ===
application: my
exited: {shutdown,{my_app,start,[normal,[noarg]]}}
type: temporary
{error,{shutdown,{my_app,start,[normal,[noarg]]}}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `my:start/2` should take two arguments but in the child specification you only give it one argument (`{8077,none}`). You could change the child spec to:

```
{my, {my, start, [8077,none]}, permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [my]}
```

As an aside your indentation and line breaking of the Supervisor Specification is a bit off making it difficult to see what belongs to what.

**EDIT: Comment to new error**

This is not the same problem as before. You are getting a new error, **eaddrinuse**, which normally means you are trying to use an IP address/port which is already in use. This would imply you are doing some socket programming in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Your supervisor specifies that my:start should take one argument, but it takes two. You probably want to change the child spec to:

```
{one_for_one, 10, 60},[{my, {my, start, [8077,none]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `my:start/2` provides a wrong return value.
Supervisor expects tuple `{ok,Pid}`, while your function simply returns `ok` (the last call is to `io:format`, which returns `ok`, so your function also does).
If you want to use a supervisor, you must spawn a new process and link it to the supervisor. For example 
`start(_) -> {ok,spawn_link(fun() -> io:format("~w started~n",[self()]),timer:sleep(5000),io:format("~w exiting~n",[self()]) end)}.`
should do the job for you.